# Use taxonomy path for a node's path alias

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

Is it possible to use a token to reference the alias of a taxonomy term in the pattern of an automatic alias for a node type where that term has been selected, in Drupal 8? (Let's assume a single taxonomy term is selected.)

For example: If one has a taxonomy of *Names* where the values are *James*, *Margaret*, *Daniel* and each name has a path assigned to it (`/news/jim`, `/news/peggy`, `/news/dan`) is it possible to construct an automatic path for "News" node types where the pattern is something like `[taxonomy:Names:path]/[node:title]` so that if one selects "*Margaret*" from the *Names* list and gives the node a title of "*Summer Vacation 2017,*" it will result in the automatic node path of `/news/peggy/summer-vacation-2017`?

All the references to path aliases based on taxonomy that I have found use the entity value of the term, which I don't want. I don't want `/news/margaret/summer-vacation-2017` as the result of the above example.

Answer (score 6):

Using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), it should be quiet easy with a pattern like :

Normal way :

```
news/[node:{NAME_OF_TAXONOMY_FIELD}:entity:name]/[node:title]
```

With hierarchy :

```
news/[node:{NAME_OF_TAXONOMY_FIELD}:entity:parents:join-path]/[node:{NAME_OF_TAXONOMY_FIELD}:entity:name]/[node:title]
```

In your case, this should work

```
[node:{NAME_OF_TAXONOMY_FIELD}:entity:url]/[node:title]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement hook_pathauto_alias_alter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_alias_alter().
 */
 function MYMODULE_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {

  if ($context['module'] != 'node') {
    return;
  }

  $node = $context['data']['node'];

  // here you can write your logic to get the taxonomy term url alias
  // something like:
  //read out the taxonomy term field of your node
  // get the term $term
  // get the URL Alias of it
  $options =
    [
      'absolute' => false,
    ];
    $termUrl = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', ['taxonomy_term' => $term->id()], $options);

    if ($termUrl && strpos($termUrl,'/taxonomy/term/' === false)) {
      $aliasPath = str_replace('/' . $languageId . '/', '/',$termUrl->toString());
    }
    $alias = $aliasPath . $alias;

  }
```